# Passing geometry dataset type to gdal.Warp() for a clip operation - order of operations and file type confusion

Tags: python, gdal, geojson, clip, gdalwarp

Trying to wrap my head around the correct order of operations and file type(s) required by `gdal.Warp()`.

I have a valid geometry object created from the shapely `object.unary_union.convex_hull` method. This geometry object represents the **boundary** of an area, and I would like to extract the raster that exists in this area.

I can use and represent this object in various formats as follows:

```py
#As a shapely geom
example_shapely = boundary.unary_union.convex_hull

#As a geojson
example_geojson = str(shapely.geometry.mapping(example_shapely))

#As a geodataframe
example_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], geometry=[example_shapely])

#As a file
example_gdf.to_file('./boundary.json')
```

I want to pass one of these through the `gdal.Warp()` python bindings to clip a raster to the boundary line. **I am able to do this with the boundary.json, but I would like to be able to do this with the shapely, GeoJSON, or gdf using `gdal.OpenEx()`**. However, I am unable to use the shapely, geojson, or gdf. I only achieve success with boundary.json. For example:

```py
boundary_ogr = gdal.OpenEx(example_gdf.to_json(), gdal.OF_VECTOR)
input_raster = gdal.Open('./outcome.tif')
output_raster = './outcome_clip.tif'

clipDs = gdal.Warp(
    destNameOrDestDS=output_raster,
    srcDSOrSrcDSTab=input_raster, 
    cutlineDSName = boundary_ogr,
    cropToCutline = True,
    dstNodata = np.nan
)

boundary_ogr = input_raster = output_raster = clipDs = None
```

I receive the following error: `ERROR 1: Cannot open <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x1544b1240> >.` Sometimes it does run, but it is not clipped to the boundary.

However, the following run does execute successfully:

```py
boundary_ogr = gdal.OpenEx(example_gdf.to_json(), gdal.OF_VECTOR)
input_raster = gdal.Open('./outcome.tif')
output_raster = './outcome_clip.tif'

clipDs = gdal.Warp(
    destNameOrDestDS=output_raster,
    srcDSOrSrcDSTab=input_raster,
    cutlineDSName = './boundary.json',
    cropToCutline = True,
    dstNodata = np.nan
)

boundary_ogr = input_raster = output_raster = clipDs = None
```

My primary question(s):

How can I use `gdal.OpenEx(boundary.to_json(), gdal.OF_VECTOR)` with `gdal.Warp()`? Or must I write the geometry object to a file and then pass it to `gdal.Warp()`?

Comment: By https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Warp the function wants to get a dataset and layer. Maybe writing output into memory instead of file with a MEM driver could be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I'm not sure I follow. Could you provide a bit more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the geojson string to `gdal.Warp`.

```
input_raster = gdal.Open('./outcome.tif')
output_raster = './outcome_clip.tif'

clipDs = gdal.Warp(
    destNameOrDestDS=output_raster,
    srcDSOrSrcDSTab=input_raster,
    cutlineDSName = example_gdf.to_json(),
    cropToCutline = True,
    dstNodata = np.nan
)
```

E.g. given this raster and polygon gdf:

[image]

The above code produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is definitely in the right direction and close to my original solution. However, I'm getting the following error: `ERROR 3: ./outcome_clip.tif: Free disk space available is 347494924288 bytes, whereas 2854650336847680 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.` I've also tried enforcing width, height, outputbounds, and more to no avail. Any ideas? If we can fix it I will mark this solution as accepted!

Comment: I guess that your cutline is covering a very large area and therefore the outcome_clip.tif would be huge. Check your geometry, and consider if it may have some issues for example due to being in another coordinate system than you believe.

Comment: @bashity I can't reproduce. Please edit your question to include output of `gdal.Info(input_raster)` and `gdal.Info(boundary_ogr)` and I'll look further.